# Covariance between a variable and an interaction variable

Tags: interaction, covariance

If I have two independent variables $X$ and $Y$, then $Cov(X,Y)=0$. Now let $Z = X*Y$. Then I would assume $Cov(X,Z)\ne 0$, but given the expecations, variances and covariances of $X$ and $Y$ is there are formula I can use to calculate how big it should be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if I am clear about your question.
\begin{align}
Cov(X,Z)&=Cov(X,XY)\\
&=E(X^2Y)-E(X)E(XY)\\
\text{(because of independence)} &= E(X^2)E(Y)-E^2(X)E(Y)\\
&=E(Y)Var(X)
\end{align}